# VHDL shift operators?

Tags: process, while-loop, vhdl, shift, synthesis

I'm still trying to get used to some of the quirks of VHDL and I'm having a bit of an issue. First off, I understand that shift operators like rol, ror, ssl, srl, etc. are not synthesizeable. The purpose of this lab is to use a golden model to check against a synthesizeable version of the same thing in a testbench.

Now, the purpose of this program is to convert thermometer code into a 3-bit binary number. So, in other words, thermometer code "00000001" = "001", "00000011" = "010", "00000111" = "011", etc. I'm basically trying to count the number of 1's in the string from right to left. There will be no case where a '0' is placed between the string of 1's, so the vector "00011101" is invalid and will never occur.

I've devised a non-synthesizeable (and so far, non-compile-able) algorithm that I can't figure out how to get working. Basically, the idea is to read the thermometer code, shift it right and increment a counter until the thermometer code equals zero, and then assign the counter value to the 3-bit std_logic_vector. Below is the code I've done so-far.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity therm2bin_g is
    port(therm : inout std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- thermometer code
         bin : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- binary code 
         i : integer range 0 to 7);
end therm2bin_g;    

architecture behavioral_g of therm2bin_g is
begin

golden : process(therm)
begin

    while(therm /= "00000000") loop
        therm <= therm srl 1;
        i = i + 1;      
    end loop;

    bin <= std_logic'(to_unsigned(i,3));

end process golden;
behavioral_g;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63734/vhdl-shift-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a version that is synthesisable. the *while* loop is replaced by a *for* loop. *srl* is implemented explicitly:

```
entity therm2bin_g is
port(therm : inout std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- thermometer code
     bin : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- binary code 
     i : out integer range 0 to 7);
end therm2bin_g;    

architecture behavioral_g of therm2bin_g is
begin

golden : process(therm)
    variable i_internal: integer range 0 to 7;
begin
    i_internal:=0;
    for idx in 0 to therm'length loop
        if therm/="0000000" then
            therm<='0' & therm(therm'left downto 1);
            i_internal := i_internal + 1;     
        end if;
    end loop;

    bin<=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i_internal,bin'length));
    i<=i_internal;

end process golden;
end behavioral_g;
```

Answer (score 1):

"... operators like rol, ror, ssl, srl, etc. are not synthesizeable..."
Who says that on who's authority? Have you checked? On which synthesis tool? Was it a recent version, or a version from the early 1990s?

Note that the argument that *some* tools *might* not support it is just silly. The fact that *some kitchens* might not have an oven does not stop people from writing recipes for cake.